# Div suddenly jumps to top of page after jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to coding and now trying to build my first website.
Apologies in advance if I have completely overlooked something very basic here!
I have a div on the bottom of my page which I made bounce when the mouse moves on it with jQuery, but for some reason it then suddenly jumps completely to the top of the page.

This is the jQuery I used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#playShowreelTotal").mousemove(function(){
        $("#playShowreelTotal").effect("bounce", {times:3}, 600);
    });
});
```

The CSS for this div looks like this:

```
#playShowreelTotal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 15px;
}
```

It would be really great if anyone had an idea what is happening here!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you try and reproduce it here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-excg5k?file=index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just put all the code into the link you sent me.... weirdly enough the div is not jumping anymore! So I guess that makes it slightly impossible for you to help me with this! Thanks anyway though! It's a bit of a mystery to me.. I might have to just keep going through the code myself, and see if I can figure it out somehow..

Comment: Check the JQ version and also the UI version then. Also, try giving fixed height to your playShowreelTotal div.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed it in the end:)

Comment: You're welcome. Care to share what the problem was?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for such a late reply. I thought it was solved but then it was suddenly doing it again haha. I tried your suggestions, but it didn't work and I really couldn't figure out what the problem was, so I have decided to leave it for now and do an alternative animation in pure CSS, which went all fine. thanks!